# How make 2 lines in <td>

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I want to show two lines in `<td>`. And it is showing, next to each other.

```
 <td bgcolor="White">
   First Name
   (on external website)
 </td>
```

I want to be like below.
1st line bold and 2nd line will be small letters.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could add a `<br/>` to force a line break and define some CSS classes for the font-styling:

```
<style>
.name { font-weight: bold; }
.subtext { font-size: smaller; }
</style>

<td bgcolor="White" >
<span class="name">First Name</span>  <br/>
<span class="subtext">(on external website)</span>
</td>
```

---

**Update**:
For completeness, I'm also including what others have suggested: instead of using a `<br/>` element, control the line-break via CSS. This has the advantage, that you can change the behavior (remove the line-break) by simply editing the CSS:

```
<style>
.name { font-weight: bold; display:block; }
.subtext { font-size: smaller; }
</style>

<td bgcolor="White" >
<span class="name">First Name</span>
<span class="subtext">(on external website)</span>
</td>
```

Instead of using `span` elements, you could also use `div`s, which have the line-break by default (but it can be disabled by setting `display:inline` in the CSS).

Comment: If you care about future style changes with CSS, then avoid the "<br/>" tag, and use CSS like this: **span.name { display: block; }**

Answer (score 2):

```
<td bgcolor="White" >
    <span style="font-weight:bold;">First Name</span>  <br/>
    <span style="font-size:6px;">(on external website)</span>
</td>
```

like that I suppose

Comment: you could set the display:block; to have them on separate lines instead of <br/>

Answer (score 2):

As you want to style the lines differently, you need to put them in separate elements anyway, so if you use block elements they will end up as separate lines:

```
<td style="background: white;" >
  <div style="font-weight: bold;">First Name</div>
  <div style="font-size: 70%;">(on external website)</div>                                 
</td>
```

Comment: +1 This arrangement would also allow the CSS stying to remove the line separation, if desired.  Any solution with "<br/>" prevents CSS from making the change.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<span></span>` with the block attribute or `<p></p>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<td bgcolor="White" >
    <strong>First Name</strong><br />
   <small>(on external website)</small>
  </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a p tag to indicate a newline like this.

```
<td> 
    First Name   
   <p>(on external website)</p>
</td>
```

Or use a br tag like this:

```
<td> 
    First Name <br />
    (on external website)
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to add a `<br />` as @M4N writes in his answer. But since it seems, that "First Name" is some sort of title, I would recommend to use the apropriate HTML tag. Also use CSS to style your table:

HTML:

```
<td class="white">
    <h3>First Name</h3>
    <span class="small">(on external website)</span>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
.white {
    background-color: white;
}
.small {
    font-size: .8em;
}
```

Note: Because `<h3>` is a block level element, the line break is "inserted" automatically