# How to set the properties for a dynamically created table row?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I need to set the border color and border style to a table row that is dynamically created. How can i do that?

```
if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                cmd.Connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())

            {

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        JobDesignation = reader.GetString(0);
                        JobDescription = reader.GetString(1);
                        NoOfVacancies = Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(2));
                        DatePosted = Convert.ToString(reader.GetDateTime(3)).Replace("00:00:00", "");
                        jobId = reader.GetString(4);
                        int tblRows = 1;
                        int tblCols = 1;

                        Table tbl = new Table();
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tbl);
                        for (int i = 0; i < tblRows; i++)
                        {
                            TableRow tr = new TableRow();

                            for (int j = 0; j < tblCols; j++)
                            {
                                TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                               System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblBox = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
                               lblBox .Text = "Job ID:" + jobId + Environment.NewLine + "Job Designation:" + JobDesignation + Environment.NewLine + "Job Description:" + JobDescription + Environment.NewLine + "Vacancies:" + NoOfVacancies + Environment.NewLine + "Ad Posted On:" + DatePosted + "";
                               tc.Controls.Add(lblBox);
                               tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                            }

                            tr.Width = new Unit("700px");
                            tr.Height = new Unit("200px");
                            tr.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                            tr.BorderStyle = System.Web.UI.WebControls.BorderStyle.Solid;
                            tbl.Rows.Add(tr);

                        }
                        ViewState["dynamictable"] = true; 
                      } reader.NextResult();

                }

            }
```

I also want to display Job Id,Job Description, Job Designation,No Of vacancies in separate line. How can i achieve that?

Please help me.

Comment: why dont you go for repeater ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set property dynamically as below :

```
    TableRow row1 = new TableRow();
    row1.CssClass = "rowStyle1";

    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
    cell1.CssClass = "cellStyle1";


//create css class as below in your css file :

.rowStyle{
    border:1px solid red;
}
.cellStyle1{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Displaying a DB table information dynamically ,without using any controls

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/Blogs/Venkyshwe8%40gmail.com/1264/displaying-a-table-information-dynamically-without-using-any-controls

Create a Table Dynamically in ASP.NET

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=135&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 1):

try with `LiteralControl`

```
for (int j = 0; j < tblCols; j++)
{
   TableCell tc = new TableCell();
   tc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Job ID:" + jobId + "<br>" + "Job Designation:" + JobDesignation + "<br>" + "Job Description:" + JobDescription + "<br>" + "Vacancies:" + NoOfVacancies + "<br>" + "Ad Posted On:" + DatePosted + ""));
   tr.Cells.Add(tc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are talking about style, I do strongly recommend you to use CSS. Please try to include the corresponding rows in a CSS class. In a separate CSS file, you can set the properties of that class as desired.

About your second question I would recommend you to create a new row with one cell and set its colspan to tblCols. You can do this right after:

```
tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
```

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Since this is dynamic, I'm going to assume using the typical recommendations of defined styles in css classes won't do the job here - otherwise the simple solution is to set your css class (always the recommended approach)

In the case where they can't be pre-defined and can vary in style, Table inherits WebControl so you then have Table.Style which you can add all your style definitions to - ex: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.cssstylecollection.aspx

What happens though with your code above? What's your markup look like? TD can override TR border styles (ex [row border color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288611/row-border-color)) but you aren't setting any above.

For your second question:
To display on a separate line, use css for display:block so each item will show up on a new line - ex: [How make 2 lines in <TD>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662649/how-make-2-lines-in-td)